# python click: "got unexpected extra arguments"

Tags: python, python-click

I have written a small and simple interface with Click, I get this error "Error: Got unexpected extra arguments" and I just can't figure out why this occurs?

Here is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "transcov",
    description = "A software for mapping coverage around transcription start sites",
    packages=find_packages("src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    #test_suite="test",
    install_requires=['pysam>=0.15.4', 'numpy>=1.18.1', 'attrs>=19.3.0', 'click>=7.1.1'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['transcov = transcov.cli:cli'],
    },
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

Here is my cli.py file:

```
import click

from .generator import generate_coverage_matrix
from .preprocessor import preprocess
from .collapser import collapse

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.argument('annotation_file')
@click.option('-o', '--output-file', default='transcription_start_sites.tsv')
def preprocess(annotation_file, output_file):
    preprocess(annotation_file, output_file)

@cli.command()
@click.argument('bam_file')
@click.argument('tss_file')
@click.option('-k', '--region-size', default=10000)
@click.option('-o', '--output-file', default='coverage_matrix.npy')
def generate(bam_file, tss_file, region_size, output_file):
    generate_coverage_matrix(bam_file, tss_file, region_size, output_file)

@cli.command()
@click.argument('matrices', nargs=-1)
@click.option('-o', '--output-file', default='collapsed_matrix.npy')
@click.option('--uint32', is_flag=True)
def collapse(matrices, output_file, uint32):
    if len(matrices) > 0:
        collapse(matrices, output_file, uint32)
```

And here is the error that I get when calling my program:

```
$ transcov preprocess -o gencodes/gencode.v19.annotation.tss.tsv gencodes/gencode.v19.annotation.gff3
Usage: gencodes/gencode.v19.annotation.tss.tsv [OPTIONS] ANNOTATION_FILE
Try 'gencodes/gencode.v19.annotation.tss.tsv --help' for help.

Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (e n c o d e s / g e n c o d e . v 1 9 . a n n o t a t i o n . g f f 3)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Have I missed something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `preprocess` function calls itself, resulting in the "unexpected extra arguments" error (see [Click: "Got unexpected extra arguments" when passing string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34904328/click-got-unexpected-extra-arguments-when-passing-string) for a similar case). This is because its definition hides the one that you imported from `.preprocessor`.

You should instead import the external `preprocess` function using a different name, e.g.:

```
from .preprocessor import preprocess as _preprocess

@cli.command()
@click.argument('annotation_file')
@click.option('-o', '--output-file', default='transcription_start_sites.tsv')
def preprocess(annotation_file, output_file):
    _preprocess(annotation_file, output_file)
```

Alternatively, you can import the `preprocessor` module:

```
from . import preprocessor
```

and then access the function using:

```
preprocessor.preprocess
```

Comment: The same thing will happen for `collapse`, just so you're aware